Why does HDMI splitter have issues on Windows but not with macOS?
I have a presentation setup in a church, consisting of Dell Inspiron 5415 laptop (Windows 11) from which I run an HDMI cable to a (powered) HDMI splitter (Pro Signal PSG3430); from there, one HDMI cable runs to a projector and a second runs to a TV. The laptop, projector and TV all have native HDMI ports (i.e. no adapters). Windows is set to extend the display: main screen is the laptop screen, extended one is the HDMI out.
When I power everything up, the extended desktop appears on the projector perfectly, but the TV shows a blank screen as if there is nothing connected/no valid signal. Plugging the laptop directly into the TV (i.e. without the splitter) it works, but as soon as the splitter is put between then, the TV stays blank - even though the graphics settings in Windows are identical and even if the projector is not connected to the splitter. Tried all combinations of cables, with/out projector connected, power on and boot order, and cannot get anything on the TV screen if the HDMI splitter is involved. The projector is fine in all setups.
But, if I replace the Windows laptop with my MacBook Pro (2023 Apple M3; Sonoma 14.7), the TV immediately works fine (as does the projector) and if I then unplug the MacBook Pro and go back to the Windows laptop, that works as well! But after the system is powered off the problem recurs until I use the MacBook Pro. The Windows graphics settings (resolution, colour depth, refresh rate, driver) appear identical when it is working and when it is not.
This shows that the setup and all components are fine, but for some reason the Windows-splitter-TV config doesn’t work until I’ve plugged the MacBook Pro in first. Obviously, this workaround is not viable long term.
I am completely at a loss: it makes no sense to me and I can’t find any Windows graphics settings that differ between working and non-working configs. Maybe there’s something about the signal timing that the MacBook Pro handles and Windows doesn’t?

Update: This is a new setup, previously was using VGA not HDMI (and a different TV). This is the second splitter I've tried; on the first one the TV showed output but the colours were completely distorted etc. Drivers/firmware is up to date; splitter has almost no info with it. Device identifies as something like HDMI 4K — can't find the picture I took of the screen (to compare settings with direct connection) to confirm right now.
And if I plug the TV in directly, it detects it as "TOSHIBA", whereas the splitter is identified as a specific item — not the projector or the TV.

Was this working previously? Does a different Windows laptop work OK? Have you checked for and installed the latest available drivers and firmware for the laptop? Does the splitter have any documentation on making it work with a Windows computer? How does Windows identify the device connected via the HDMI?

@music2myear; this is a new setup, previously was using VGA not HDMI (and a different TV). This is the second splitter I've tried; on the first one the TV showed output but the colours were completely distorted etc. Drivers/firmware is up to date; splitter has almost no info with it. Device identifies as something like HDMI 4K - can't find the picture I took of the screen (to compare settings with direct connection) to confirm right now.

Clarifying on the latter: if I plug the TV in directly, it detects it as "TOSHIBA", whereas the splitter is identified as a specific item -- not the projector or the TV.

Add that information to the question itself to make it more clear and complete.

"if I then unplug the MacBook Pro and go back to the Windows laptop, that works as well!" Suggests that there is a problem with HDCP negotiation. Perhaps the mac is negotiating properly (or is not using HDCP) and it works, and then the TV doesn't try again (and fail) because it is unaware the laptop has been swapped out. Could be fiction, but might be a lead: chaining is often the problem (as is compliant cabling)

@Yorik I was quite excited by this one (I wasn't familiar with HDCP) but I tried today disabling HDCP on the Windows laptop (using the AMD Radeon tool) and it still didn't work :(
